# How to get full 1000 score in Zork: Grand Inquisitor?

Tags: zork

I've just finished replaying an old piece of childhood of mine - Zork: Grand Inquisitor (the GOG version). At the end of the game I got a score of 862 of 1000 or something like that.

Which made me wonder - what did I miss? What is the score awarded for anyway? How do you get the full 1000?

Searching the internet didn't give me any answers. I saw at least one walkthrough that claimed to have 1000 score at the end, but that was the only place the word "score" appeared in it.

To be honest, I've only played the three graphical installments of Zork, so I'm not too well versed in its vast lore and traditions. Perhaps if I was, I would know the answer.

Comment: [Last Lousy Point](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LastLousyPoint) was definitely a thing Zork did, often and even jokingly, but it would be hard to say which things you still needed to do.  Zork "lore" such as it is varies wildly, compare Nemesis and GI, or look up Zork Zero, GI draws most of it's flavor from that one.  My guess is that there are easter eggs or one-liners that award more points that you missed.  I'll see what I can find.

Comment: @Radhil - I did find an easter-egg list on the web and there were definitely things on it that I haven't tried, but it didn't say anything about score points. Perhaps I should try those (and try to come up with other things it doesn't list).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug that occurred when GOG replaced the Dosbox version of the game with the SCUMM version. I used to always get full score without trying in the old version, now I never can.

I’ve been going through the game checking my score with F7 and writing down all the points. So far I don’t see any way to gain extra points or lose points (I thought casting Golgatem over flood dam #3 might add extra points for example). When I have completed my list of points and actions I’ll post it here.

Comment: Are you also trying the "pointless" things like clicking the eggplants or wrong things or whatever? Basically - trying to get every piece of sound and animation to play?

Comment: I believe this is accurate. I remember playing the old version, and it would always end on 1000 points. The rank awarded is also rather suggestive that "you get 1000 points for winning."